# Laravel phpspreadsheet passing data with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I plan to use phpspreadsheet to extract our expenses directly from the database. I'm still on the tutorial part but I was considering that I need to pass data from front end (a select option) to back end to determine from what branch and type of expense that I will be getting from the database. If directly from href="/sampleRoute" from an anchor tag, it will download but if I try to go through ajax it won't.

a code sample of my route, ajax and controller. the code inside the controller is directly from a tutorial but the ajax is just me trying something else.

ROUTE

`Route::get('/excel_tf_breakdown', 'excelController@excel_tf_breakdown');`

AJAX

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnExport', function(){
    test = 'test';

    $.ajax({
        url: '/excel_tf_breakdown',
        data: {
            test:test
        },
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function excel_tf_breakdown(Request $request){
    info($request->test);

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', '#');
    $sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'First');
    $sheet->setCellValue('A3', 'First');
    $sheet->setCellValue('A4', 'First');

    $filename = 'sample.xlsx';

    //redirect output to client
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

The request->test works but it does not download the excel file. I'd like to know how I can export to excel with ajax.

Comment: I recommend to save the excel in a temp folder and then obtain the URL to access that file and return that URL to the Ajax function. And then when ajax is successful, use `window.location = <URL>;` and it will download the file.

Comment: The phpspreadsheet docs seem to only have a direct download option though. May I know how exactly can I do that?

Comment: Please check my answer below. I have added one line in your ajax code in success call back. I hope it does what you need.

Comment: Did you try that? Is it working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing,

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnExport', function(){
    test = 'test';

    $.ajax({
        url: '/excel_tf_breakdown',
        data: {
            test:test
        },
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            window.open('http://YOUR_URL','_blank' ); // You need to do this only.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't return as a success so it's not reading the success:function. by YOUR_URL do you mean /excel_tf_breakdown?

Comment: Remove Exit from your controller function.

Comment: but it does not return the data "test" that I sent.

Comment: for example the 'test' variable I sent through ajax is a value of a 'branch' in the database so that would output only expenses based on what 'branch' I picked.

Comment: You mean to say, the `test` value is not received in the controller function?

Comment: the one line that you added does not but downloads the file.

Comment: Did you write full URL in that one line?

Comment: you mean localhost:8000/excel_tf_breakdown

Comment: The same URL using which with the browser you can download the excel sheet.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed one thing, you should change the `method: 'post',` in your ajax function. That is the reason why you are not getting `test` in your PHP function.

Comment: still the same. I'm currently trying to do it in a form with hidden inputs hopefully it works.

Comment: If you print something (`print_r('It prints');die;`) in the first line of that function, can you see it in the network tab of the browser console? I doubt that the ajax request is not reaching there.